# Fixed margin at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, html

I've a page with a main scrollable div like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  #mydiv{
  overflow: auto;
  width: 300px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mydiv">content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I have a fixed margin (for example 30px) at the bottom of the page?
The div can have a small or big height (depending on the screen size), but the margin should be fixed.
Thanks in advice

Comment: Are you looking for a sticky footer? Try googling the term.  The first result is http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another div either inside your existing or outside depending on how you want your page to layout.  Then apply this style to the div `#myftr { margin: 30px; }`

Something like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/rhoenig/XxuvE/

Answer (score 1):

you can simply define the margin-bottom in your css  like this :-

#mydiv{
      overflow: auto;
      width: 300px;
      border:1px solid red;
      margin-bottom:30px;
      }

or see the demo :-http://jsfiddle.net/XxuvE/4/

Comment: I had already tried this solution. I just added a few details to the question